# Material-UI DateRangerPicker remove dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

does anyone know how to remove the dd/mm/yyyy from this control, not just the text but the space it takes?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Inside your TextField add helperText as empty String.

 <TextField {...startProps} variant="standard" helperText=""/>
 <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
 <TextField {...endProps} variant="standard" helperText=""/>
```